# Why can't I resize my image from cloudinary

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my CSS code for the Image (It's staying at the original size from cloudinary)

```
.img-container {
position: relative;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
#skills-img {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
}
```

My HTML for the Image

```
<div class="img-container">
     <img src="" id="skills-image" alt="Skill">
</div>
```

Any ideas on why it wont let me resize the cloudinary image?

TIA Connor

Comment: Looks like a typo: the CSS is for `#skills-img`, the image id in HTML is `skills-image`

Comment: Wow I feel thick now! thank you

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

Comment: For your future reference, I inspected the image element (in a browser) to see if it had invalid CSS. The browser said the image didn't have any CSS. That meant the CSS selector for the image id wasn't matched.. Looking at the HTML revealed the problem.

Comment: Thanks that's great advice

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo: the `CSS` is for `#skills-img`, the image id in HTML is `skills-image`

```css
.img-container {
position: relative;
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
#skills-img {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
object-fit: contain;
border-radius: 50%;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
     <img src="" id="skills-img" alt="Skill">
</div>
```

i hope you got your solution .